# Shortcut for undoing a chosen version in Git conflict

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio Code when want to resolve a Git conflict, we choose one of the versions or all of them, but accidentally we figure out it isn't what we want.

Is there any shortcut to undo the chosen version and lets to choose other options?

Comment: Do you know how to do it without a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: you know there are several ways to do that such as restoring and commit again .
if I get you .you mean do I know how to do that without shortcut ,no I don't know